# How to make a carousel with multiple images in Vuetify?

Tags: vuetify.js

I want to make a carousel with multiple images like this:

[image: Multiple images carousel]

It should slide a single image on arrow click.

There is a [feature request](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/1886), but how to make it until it is fixed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the following workaround:

```
<v-carousel>
  <v-carousel-item :key="i" v-for="i in 5">
    <v-layout row>
      <v-flex xs4 :key="j" v-for="j in 3">
        <img :src="'https://placehold.it/380x500/?text=' + i + '-' + j" alt="">
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>
```

But it scrolls a group of images at once. See the [**demo**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GGbwOW).

**UPDATE:** You can use [Vue2-Siema](https://github.com/sainf/vue2-siema), which is a Vue 2 wrapper for [Siema](https://pawelgrzybek.github.io/siema/) - a lightweight carousel library. See the [**demo**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rZNxNx).

Answer (score 10):

If you want a more fine-grained control over the look and functionality of your carousel
(touch, speed, momentum, number of images per slide, responsive behavior ...), and don't want to implement it from scratch, I recommend you use [Vue-Awesome-Swiper](https://surmon-china.github.io/vue-awesome-swiper/) as a Vue plugin and stay away from Vuetify when it comes to carousels and image galleries, at least until it's more complete in that regard.

Vue-Awesome-Swiper in a thin vue wrapper around the very powerful [Swiper.js](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/#initialize) library which is, by it's own developers words:

> The most modern mobile touch slider with hardware accelerated transitions

Here's the screenshot of a carousel with multiple images:

[image: horizontal carousel]

([Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/lybete/pen/BVXzqm))

and here's the screenshot of an image gallery with thumbs:

[image: image gallery with thumbs]

([Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/lybete/pen/ERqKpR))

Here's a code snippet for the first screenshot:

```js
Vue.use(VueAwesomeSwiper);
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    swiperSlides: [
      "pink",
      "red",
      "yellow",
      "purple",
      "green",
      "orange",
      "blue"
    ],
    swiperOption: {
      initialSlide: 0,
      slidesPerView: 4,
      spaceBetween: 20,
      freeMode: true,
      watchOverflow: true,
      breakpoints: {
        1904: {
          slidesPerView: 4,
          spaceBetween: 20
        },
        1264: {
          slidesPerView: 4,
          spaceBetween: 20
        },
        960: {
          slidesPerView: 4,
          spaceBetween: 50
        },
        600: {
          slidesPerView: 3,
          spaceBetween: 150
        },
        400: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
          spaceBetween: 150
        }
      },
      pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        clickable: true
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
      }
    }
  }),
  computed: {
    swiper() {
      return this.$refs.mySwiper.swiper;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // current swiper instance
    this.swiper.slideTo(3, 1000, false);
  },
  methods: {
    callback() {
      //read the API docs to see which slider events are available
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-awesome-swiper@3.1.2/dist/vue-awesome-swiper.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-card id="product">
        <swiper :options="swiperOption" ref="mySwiper" @someSwiperEvent="callback">
          <!-- slides -->
          <swiper-slide v-for="(slide, index) in swiperSlides" :key="index">
            <v-avatar tile="tile" size="150px" :color="slide">
              <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/a8813qmu9f5yixz/shoe_left.png?raw=1">
            </v-avatar>
          </swiper-slide>

          <!-- Optional controls -->
          <div class="swiper-pagination" slot="pagination"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-prev" slot="button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next" slot="button-next"></div>
        </swiper>
      </v-card>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

If you're using the vue-cli, you import Vue-Awesome-Swiper in your main js file and register it as a Vue plugin, as you would with Vuetify:

```
import VueAwesomeSwiper from 'vue-awesome-swiper';
import 'swiper/dist/css/swiper.css';
Vue.use(VueAwesomeSwiper);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! The problem with _vue-awesome-swiper_ is that it is bloated - the bundle weights 120KB minified. A more lightweight alternative is [vue-tiny-slider](https://github.com/viktorlarsson/vue-tiny-slider), based on [tiny-slider](https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider), which weights only 32KB minified.

Comment: Even more lightweight alternative is [vue-siema](https://github.com/sainf/vue2-siema), based on [siema](https://pawelgrzybek.com/siema/), which is only 15KB minified.

Comment: I want to highlight that vuetify has come along way since this question and it does support this functionality now you can see how to do it here https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/slide-groups